# EF5 Code First Migration problems publishing to IIS

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, connection-string, entity-framework-migrations

I've created a MVC 4 project which uses EF5 Code First with migrations.
Because I was new to this topic I used the following [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx).

Now that the development is finished I want to publish to IIS (I use FTP or Web deployment package). So before publishing I changed the connectionstring to the right db server.
But after publishing the site I get an exception when accessing pages which make use of the DB. The exceptions refers to the fact that he can't connect to the database.

Because of these problems I decided to try it out locally on another DB server than the default one "(LocalDB)\v11.0". BTW: "(LocalDB)\v11.0" works like a charm...
While debugging I got a better look at the error. 
Here is an image of the error:
[image: Picture of the Error]

What I've already tried:

- Generate a sql script by executing  "Update-Database -Script
  -SourceMigration:$InitialDatabase" in the Package manager console. After I ran this script on the dbserver to create the db. Tables were
  created but the error was still there.
- I changed my connectionstring to all kinds of combination with no
  results
- I already used a custom user for the app pool in ISS and gave this user full rights to the DB server and the db.

Here is the most important part of my web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=LOCALHOST\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=ProjectX;Integrated Security=TRUE;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And

```
<entityFramework>
 <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
   <parameters>
     <parameter value="Data Source=LOCALHOST\MSSQLSERVER; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
   </parameters>
 </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```

My DBCcontext class constructor looks like

```
public DBContext(): base("DefaultConnection")
{
}
```

I guess I am missing something, this is the first time I use EF Code First with migrations.
This problem is really driving me crazy. I am out of ideas.

Comment: what are the inner exceptions?

Comment: I can't access the project right now. I will paste them later this day. But It was something about a ProviderManifestToken for EF Code First...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that the problem was caused by the connectionstring.
The string was incorrect, seems like you if you have a default SQL Server you just need to use 
"Data Source=LOCALHOST".

I guess because of all the problems I had that day with the deployment i overlooked the easy parts. Yust make sure you the following things are true when you have problems like I did:

1. Your connectionstring has the same name as your DBContext. Another sollution could be to do like i did and add the connectionstring name to the base:

   public DBContext(): base("DefaultConnection")
   {
   }
2. If you also have the defaultconnectionfactory set. Make sure to also update the Data Source there. This was one of the problems I struggled with. I didn't check the bottom of my web.config ...

If the problem still persists you can use EF profiler to have a look at the connectionstring when your app of site is accessing the DB.